# How do I use a variable so that it is inside and outside of a function

Tags: function, variables, if-statement, arguments, python-3.4

I would like to know how I can use a variable in a function but then outside of the function as well.
Here is a part of my code which is supposed to add 1 to the score when the answer is correct, then print out the overall score afterwards (there is more than one function so I need to the score to be outside of the function):

```
score=0
def Geography(score):
#Question 1
qa1= input("What is the capital of England? ")
if qa1.lower() == ("london"):
    print ("Correct you gain 1 point")
    score=score+1
else:
    print ("Incorrect")

Geography(score)
print ("This quiz has ended. Your score is " , score, ".")
```

As you can see, I have tried to use arguments however the code still returns the score as 0 at the end no matter if the person has got the answer right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `score` from the function and assign it back to `score`

```
score=0
def Geography(score):
    #Question 1
    qa1= input("What is the capital of England? ")
    if qa1.lower() == ("london"):
        print ("Correct you gain 1 point")
        score=score+1
    else:
        print ("Incorrect")
    return score

score = Geography(score)
print ("This quiz has ended. Your score is " , score, ".")
```

Comment: This causes the code to repeat itself but still says that the score is 0

Comment: How does it cause the code to repeat itself? I just tested it and it worked fine. Do you have more things in your code that you haven't put in the question?

Comment: Sorry, the code doesnt repeat anymore, that was my fault.  There is more than 1 function in which the user must choose between so when calling the function it is in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "global" before variable "score" and access it again in the "def Geography():" function. This code should work for all "def" functions in code:

```
global score
score = 0


def Geography():
    # Question 1
    global score
    qa1 = input("What is the capital of England? ")
    if qa1.lower() == ("london"):
        print("Correct you gain 1 point")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect")


Geography()
print("This quiz has ended. Your score is ", score, ".")
```