# Cannot Access Variable Outside of Function

Tags: python

I keep getting the following error when trying to access a variable from one function inside another function.

NameError: global name 'savemovieurl' is not defined

how can i access the "savemovieurl" from the function "tmdb_posters" inside "dynamic_data_entry" to save it to the database?

i've tried adding global to the variable name, and had no success.

```
import requests
import urllib

import sqlite3
import time
import datetime
import random



movie = raw_input('Enter your movie: ')
print('You searched for: ', movie)

def imdb_id_from_title(title):
    """ return IMDb movie id for search string

        Args::
            title (str): the movie title search string
        Returns: 
            str. IMDB id, e.g., 'tt0095016' 
            None. If no match was found
    """
    pattern = 'http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&tt=on&q={movie_title}'
    url = pattern.format(movie_title=urllib.quote(title))
    r = requests.get(url)
    res = r.json()
    # sections in descending order or preference
    for section in ['popular','exact','substring']:
        key = 'title_' + section 
        if key in res:
            return res[key][0]['id']

if __name__=="__main__":
    title = movie
    imdb_info_returned = ("{1}".format(title, imdb_id_from_title(title)))
    print imdb_info_returned


import os
import requests

CONFIG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/configuration?api_key={key}'
IMG_PATTERN = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{imdbid}/images?api_key={key}' 
KEY = '47db65094c31430c5a2b65112088d70e'

imdb_id_input = imdb_info_returned
print('You searched for: ', imdb_id_input)



def _get_json(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

def _download_images(urls, path='.'):
    """download all images in list 'urls' to 'path' """

    for nr, url in enumerate(urls):
        r = requests.get(url)
        filetype = r.headers['content-type'].split('/')[-1]
        filename = 'poster_{0}.{1}'.format(nr+1,filetype)
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        with open(filepath,'wb') as w:
            w.write(r.content)

def get_poster_urls(imdbid):
    """ return image urls of posters for IMDB id
        returns all poster images from 'themoviedb.org'. Uses the
        maximum available size. 
        Args:
            imdbid (str): IMDB id of the movie
        Returns:
            list: list of urls to the images
    """
    config = _get_json(CONFIG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY))
    base_url = config['images']['base_url']
    sizes = config['images']['poster_sizes']

    """
        'sizes' should be sorted in ascending order, so
            max_size = sizes[-1]
        should get the largest size as well.        
    """
    def size_str_to_int(x):
        return float("inf") if x == 'original' else int(x[1:])
    max_size = max(sizes, key=size_str_to_int)

    posters = _get_json(IMG_PATTERN.format(key=KEY,imdbid=imdbid))['posters']
    poster_urls = []


    rel_path = posters[0]['file_path']
    url = "{0}{1}{2}".format(base_url, max_size, rel_path)
    poster_urls.append(url) 

    return poster_urls

def tmdb_posters(imdbid, count=None, outpath='.'):    
    urls = get_poster_urls(imdbid)
    if count is not None:
        urls = urls[:count]
    _download_images(urls, outpath)




    savemovieurl = urls
    print savemovieurl





conn = sqlite3.connect('tutorial.db')
c = conn.cursor()



def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies(unix REAL, datestamp TEXT, keyword TEXT, value REAL, moviename TEXT, movieimage TEXT, movieurl TEXT)")

def data_entry():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO movies VALUES(1452549219,'2016-01-11 13:53:39','Python',6,'movienamehere1', 'savemovieurl', 'movieurlhere1')")
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()



def dynamic_data_entry(argument) :
    unix = time.time()
    date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H: %M: %S'))
    keyword = 'keyword_string'
    movieurl = 'bing.com'
    value = random.randrange(0,10)
    savemovieurl2 = 'testimageurl.com'
    print argument
    c.execute("INSERT INTO movies (unix, datestamp, keyword, value, moviename, movieimage, movieurl) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (unix, date, keyword, value, movie, savemovieurl2, movieurl))
    conn.commit()

create_table()
#data_entry()

for i in range(10) :
    dynamic_data_entry(savemovieurl)
    time.sleep(1)
c.close()
conn.close()



if __name__=="__main__":
    tmdb_posters(imdb_id_input)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the keyword `return`? Don't *print* values with your functions -- *return* them, so that the calling code can use them or pass them along.

Comment: so if i replace the prints with return it should work?

Comment: @JohnColeman and Sofia are both correct that _the answer_ to your question is to use the `return` statement. **However**, looking at your code, I don't believe that the answer is really going to help. You've taken two files that were set up to run independently and chained them together in line: this may work on occasion, but it's ultimately going to lead to an unsalvageable situation in the long run. I don't mean to sound condescending, but what you really need is a basics-of-Python tutorial: how does a python script run, what is a function, why is `if __name__ == "__main__":` there, etc.

Comment: @ReidBallard is correct that you really need to study the basics of the language. Ambition is good, but if you are uncertain about some of the basic semantics of the language (e.g. how variable scope works and the mechanics of function calls and returns) then what you are attempting seems entirely too ambitious for your current level of knowledge. Python has a gentle learning curve, you should be able to pick up enough of the basics in just a couple of weeks. You already seem to know some of them, so that's a good start.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but I need this app to work. Can anyone help me get it running? I tried using returns with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered here: [How do I use a variable so that it is inside and outside of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36186687/4862506)

I know I should comment this however for some reason I can't so I just thought I'd write it as an answer instead. I hope this helps.

Comment: for the function (dynamic_data_entry), i pass the returned value from tmdb_posters as the argument for the function. 

however, i can print the argument with a print function with no error, but when i try to save the argument to a variable to use to save in the database, i get an error.

why can i print the argument, but not save it to a variable?